# lambda function replace column name with name_with_spaces

Tags: python, pandas

I have some code:

```
df.groupby(['Image','Roi']).apply(lambda x: x.loc[~(x.duplicated(['Total']) & x.Total.isnull())])
```

I wish to replace "Total" with a longer PANDAS column name which includes spaces, but this raises a syntax error:

```
df.groupby(['Image','Roi']).apply(lambda x: x.loc[~(x.duplicated(['Total size']) & x.['Total size'].isnull())])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a *dot* when accessing an array element:

```
x.['Total size'].isnull()
 ^
```

Instead, just follow with bracket:

```
x['Total size'].isnull()
```